# Как называется эта штука , которая находиться вверху toolbar, и как менять её цвет при переходе на разные фрагменты?

Tags: android, view

Я хотел бы узнать название этого элемента, выше toolbar с примером код, где её цвет будет меняться в зависимости от фрагмента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]2vx1.png

Comment: статья по разным "UI-штукам" - https://habr.com/ru/company/youla/blog/540768/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется Status Bar. Вот например изменение цвета:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

например можно создать метод в активности:

```
public void updateStatusBarColor(String color){// hexadecimal fromat
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
}
```

и вызывать в фрагменте:

```
((ActivityName)getActivity()).updateStatusBarColor("#000000")
```

[вот здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-color-of-status-bar-in-an-android-app/) есть хороший туториал по вашему вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Эта штука называется строкой состояния.

Изменить цвет как-то так:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Цвет строки состояния -->

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
</style>
```

**P.S.** [Источник](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theme.php).